# How can I catch error from EPPlus where file doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

I have function who take FilePath and return all of Excel information into a List.
My actual problem is not the function, but the error system who don't work if my FilePath is bad or file not exist.

I try some error basic catch, but it's not work and my program crash with this message :

> System.NullReferenceException : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I paste my functions here :

```
 public List<ImportExcelModel> GetList(string filePath)
        {
            List<ImportExcelModel> ExcelList = new List<ImportExcelModel>();
            try
            {
                ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

                using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
                    int totalColumn = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; // <- Error Message is print here
                    int totalRow = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;

                    for (int row = 2; row <= totalRow; row++)
                    {
                        ImportExcelModel ll = new ImportExcelModel();
                        for (int col = 1; col <= totalColumn; col++)
                        {
                            if (col == 1) ll.DPT = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value == null ? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString();
                            if (col == 2) ll.Description = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value == null ? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString();
                            if (col == 3) ll.Conditionnement = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value == null ? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString();
                            if (col == 4) ll.StockInitial = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value == null ? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString();
                            if (col == 5) ll.Entree = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value == null ? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString();
                            if (col == 6) ll.Sortie = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value == null ? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString();
                            if (col == 7) ll.StockMini = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value == null ? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString();
                            if (col == 8) ll.StockReel = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value == null ? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString();
                            if (col == 9) ll.Localisation = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value == null ? string.Empty : worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString();
                        }
                        ExcelList.Add(ll);
                    }
                }
                return ExcelList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ExcelList;
            }
        }
```

Edit : Yes, I want empty list if I can't open file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.IO.File.Exists(path) will return true/false. Use this to find out if the file exists or not